# Access Denied Error when deleting objects only in AWS S3 bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, delete-file, access-denied, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have tried setting up policies and permissions in the following ways:

- added permission boundary of AmazonS3FullAccess
- Policy for both the IAM user policy and bucket policy are as outlined below with the only difference in the bucket policy being that it has a principal with the IAM user arn

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Statement2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:DeleteObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The DELETE function was created to delete all objects in a folder created on the S3 bucket is as follows:

```
export async function emptyBucketByPrefix(prefix) {

    let listResponse
    do {
        listResponse = await s3Client.send(new ListObjectsV2Command({Bucket: bucketName, Prefix: prefix}));
        if (!listResponse.Contents?.length) {
            break;
        }
        console.log(listResponse.Contents)
        const objects = listResponse.Contents.map(({Key}) => ({Key}));       
         
         objects.forEach(async (object)=>{
          const objectkey = object.Key;
          console.log(objectkey)
          const command = new DeleteObjectCommand({
            Bucket: bucketName,
            Key: objectkey
        });
        await s3Client.send(command); 
        })        
    } while (listResponse.IsTruncated);
}
```

The error that pops up is as follows

```
    const response = new exceptionCtor({
                     ^

AccessDenied: Access Denied
    at throwDefaultError (/home/ubuntu/LTS/node_modules/@smithy/smithy-client/dist-cjs/default-error-handler.js:8:22)
    at /home/ubuntu/LTS/node_modules/@smithy/smithy-client/dist-cjs/default-error-handler.js:18:39
    at de_DeleteObjectCommandError (/home/ubuntu/LTS/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_restXml.js:3569:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async /home/ubuntu/LTS/node_modules/@smithy/middleware-serde/dist-cjs/deserializerMiddleware.js:7:24
    at async /home/ubuntu/LTS/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-signing/dist-cjs/awsAuthMiddleware.js:14:20
    at async /home/ubuntu/LTS/node_modules/@smithy/middleware-retry/dist-cjs/retryMiddleware.js:27:46
    at async /home/ubuntu/LTS/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-sdk-s3/dist-cjs/region-redirect-endpoint-middleware.js:14:24
    at async /home/ubuntu/LTS/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-sdk-s3/dist-cjs/region-redirect-middleware.js:9:20
    at async /home/ubuntu/LTS/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-logger/dist-cjs/loggerMiddleware.js:7:26 {
  '$fault': 'client',
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: 403,
    requestId: '23TMS8N9GZVMVF5X',
    extendedRequestId: 'UcgMpS1lNrpLNE7pIs8ZgW4cUSn7v55vFVQMbcc4WmQTVYo89wZiIqZLo0MS5j4dk/gYtDCFCbY=',
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  },
  Code: 'AccessDenied',
  RequestId: '23TMS8N9GZVMVF5X',
  HostId: 'UcgMpS1lNrpLNE7pIs8ZgW4cUSn7v55vFVQMbcc4WmQTVYo89wZiIqZLo0MS5j4dk/gYtDCFCbY='
}
```

Really appreciate any insight you can provide me

I tried what I mentioned above and was looking for a smooth delete but it didn't work

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this code running on lambda or just an ec2 / ebs instance with nodejs? Either way, how are you authenticating the server in the code?

Comment: running an EC2 instance

Comment: Is there are reason why you have a permission boundary attached to the IAM roles? administrators demand this to create roles?

Comment: This is what AWS documentation says about permission boundaries. "A permissions boundary is an advanced feature for using a managed policy to set the maximum permissions that an identity-based policy can grant to an IAM entity. An entity's permissions boundary allows it to perform only the actions that are allowed by both its identity-based policies and its permissions boundaries."  [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_boundaries.html?icmpid=docs_iam_console)  I assumed this might fix the problem which is why I added it.